# How to remove specific Cobertura warning?

Tags: ant, warnings, cobertura

When i am running my ANT build script, Cobertura is complaining with the following warning. With that, i am wondering what it means really and how can i turn it off.

[`cobertura-instrument] WARN   visitEnd, No line number information found for class com.x.y.z.A.  Perhaps you need to compile with debug=true?`

ANT sample below:

```
<target name="instrument" depends="init,compile" >
    <delete file="cobertura.ser" />
    <delete dir="${instrumented}" />
    <cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented}">
        <ignore regex="org.apache.log4j.*" />
        <fileset dir="${build}" > 
            <include name="**/*.class" />
            <exclude name="**/Test*.class" />
        </fileset>
    </cobertura-instrument>
</target>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](http://old.nabble.com/Getting-line-and-branch-coverage-N-A-td17058262.html) in the cobertura mailing-list, perhaps you can try adding the debug options and see if that helps.

```
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="vars,lines,source">
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting debuglevel appears to not work for anonymous inner classes (Cobertura 1.9.4.1)?

```
[cobertura-instrument] WARN   visitEnd, No line number information found for class com.test.MyClass$1.  Perhaps you need to compile with debug=true?
```

Comment: I also see this warning for ONLY inner classes. Anyone know how to fix that?